# como renderizar no ReactJS dados de uma API?

Tags: api, react, return

desculpa galera, sou muito novato em programação e estou fazendo um projeto para uma faculdade. Consegui conectar-me a api, consigo trazer o objeto de lá, so que não consigo renderizar esses dados que são retornados, ja tentei muita coisa e nao funcionou. Alguém pode me dar uma luz? Amanha tenho que apresentá-lo e não sei como fazer.  o código está assim e perdido no que fazer ...

```
const Empresa = () => { const [itens, setItens] = useState([]) async function buscar(event) {

event.preventDefault();


const cpf = document.getElementById('cpf').value



try {

  if (cpf !== null) {
    if (cpf !== '') {
      const response = await api.post('/pacientes/atestados',
        {
          cpf
        });

        setItens(response.data);


      if (response.data !== null) {
        setItens(response);
        console.log(itens)

      }
      if (response.data == '') {
        console.log(response.data)

        alert('CPF não cadastrado')

      }


    }


    else {
      alert('Preencha todos os campos')
    }
  }
}


catch (error) {
  alert(error);

}
} return (

<>
  <Header />
  <h1>Bem vindo Empresa!</h1>
  <h2>Pesquisar Atestado</h2>

  <form >
    <div className="grupo de formulários">
      <label htmlFor="cpf"> CPF </ label>
      <input name="cpf" className="controle de formulário"
        id="cpf" placeholder="Digite o cpf do funcionário"
      />
    </ div>


    <button type="submit"
      className="form-contact-button" onClick={buscar}> Buscar atestado </ button>
  </ form>


  {/* <button id="form-contact-button2" onClick={sair}>SAIR</button> */}
</>
```

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde Wendel!

Espero que não seja tarde demais para apresentar seu trabalho.

Vou tentar te ajudar:

Primeiramente, como você definiu `api` em `api.post`?
`api` é como você definiu o nome da biblioteca que você importou?

Segundamente, você está fazendo uma requisição POST para `/pacientes/atestados`.
Lembre-se que você quer renderizar um dado do banco. Pelo que entendi pelo contexto, você quer passar um cpf e buscar o atestado do cpf, caso tenha, certo?

Se é isso que você quer, você precisa fazer uma requisição GET para o endereço, e provavelmente é melhor terminar o endereço com uma barra, já tive problemas graças à isso (ex.: /pacientes/atestados/).

Depois de usar o setItens com toda a lista de atestados, você pode fazer o seguinte:

`const resultado = itens.find( cpfPaciente => cpfPaciente === cpf );`
/* no exemplo acima, considerei que o atestado tem o campo cpfPaciente, e vai ler todos os itens e procurar pelo atestado cujo cpfPaciente é o mesmo que foi colocado no input id="cpf". Quando achar o atestado do cpf que você procurou, ele armazena em `result`.
*/

Para mostrar os dados, pode usar o hook abaixo:
`const [atestado, setAtestado] = useState({});`

Agora pode definir atestado como o resultado da busca
`setAtestado(resultado)`

No final, coloca `{atestado}` depois do botão de busca para renderizar na tela.

**DICA**:
Não use espaços e acentos em classNames (e IDs também). Um elemento pode ter uma ou mais classes, que são separadas por espaço, então em `className="grupo de formulário"`, estão sendo consideradas três classes distintas, "grupo", "de" e "formulario". Troque os espaços por hífens (-) que o css funciona melhor.